# Autoboxing Unboxing in java using Object

Tags: java, boxing, unboxing

Using `Object` type object for autoboxing is working but it is not working for unboxing. What is the reason behind it. I mean about not working of unboxing feature for Object type object. Is any special reason to implement this behaviour. Because its support autoboxing but not support unboxing.When it comes to Integer class it support both autoboxing and unboxing. And c# also supports autoboxing and unboxing for Object type object.

```
class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int x=100;
        Object iob1=new Object();

        Object iob2=x;  //Auto Boxing

        System.out.println(iob2.toString());

        int y = x + iob1;   //Unboxing is not working
        int z = x + new Integer(10); // Unboxing is working
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Swailem95 un-/boxing is described here in the jls: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7 . Basically it's about implicit conversion of primitive types to the respective `Object` type, like `int` to `Integer` and vice versa

Comment: You supposed add an int value (`x`) with an Object(`iob1`)?! maybe `else / if` for next?

Comment: How does one add `100` to `Object`. Boxing is related to, for example,  `int <-> Integer` conversion. You would need to cast `Object` to `Integer`. I really don't understand how you expect this to work.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I mean about not working of unboxing feature for Object type object this is sample code. I dont want to add int to object,  if unboxing happens then its okay. Like other unboxing supported classes. C# supports Autoboxing and unboxing both for Object type object that is why i asked wheather there is any special reason to implement this behaviour. Because its support autoboxing but not support unboxing.

Comment: Your example has no unboxing. That is my point.

Comment: @BoristheSpider According to your point. If Object replace using Integer,Then also there is no unboxing. I mean the same behaviour for different ocation using that example

Comment: In your boxing example you use an implicit upcast. `int` gets **boxed** to `Integer` and then **upcast** to `Object`. There is **no such thing** as an implicit downcast in Java. Auto-unboxing can convert `Integer` to `int` but there is no way the compiler can covert `Object` to `Integer` without an **explicit** cast. I don't understand where your confusion arises from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unboxing is working quite fine. **BUT** only for `Double`, `Integer`, etc.. `iob1` is of type `Object`, so it can't work. The jls lists types that can be un-/boxed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7).

Answer (score 1):

```
int y = x + iob1;
```

The `+` operator cannot have an `int` and an `Object` (How do you expect to add a number to an object?). See [this section from the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18):

> If the type of either operand of a `+` operator is `String`, then the operation is string concatenation.
>
> **Otherwise, the type of each of the operands of the `+` operator must be a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs.**